# Password Verify always fails

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, password-hash

The password is hashed and enters the db when i try to verify it it returns false every time i have echoed out the password going in and the db password the column in the database is the correct size

```
<?php

require_once('dbconfig.php');

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($uname, $umail, $upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS(USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);                                        

            $stmt->execute();   

            return $stmt;   
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }               
    }


    public function doLogin($uname, $umail, $upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = "SELECT USERID, USERNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = :uname OR EMAIL = :umail ";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($stmt, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
            $stmt->bindparam(':uname', $uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(':umail', $umail);
            $stmt->execute();
            $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $db_password = $userRow['PASSWORD'];

            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = :uname OR EMAIL = :umail";
            $sql = $this->conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
            $sql->bindparam(':uname', $uname);
            $sql->bindparam(':umail', $umail);
            $sql->Execute();
            $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($row == 1)
            {
                if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['PASSWORD']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['USER_SESSION'] = $userRow['USERID'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['USER_SESSION']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function doLogout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['USER_SESSION']);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

edit to the code i have added the whole user class but it is still returning false the password in the db looks like this $2y$10$16aMCo14n.QyON8dFsaFL..6Fi92LuBdWMCI3eAv3WHKJTblJKQ6q the column in the db is set to nvarchar (255) not null

Comment: The password field you are returning from the DB is also hashed? Are you using `password_hash`?

Comment: I’ve put password_has on the registration does it need to go on the login as well I’m still new to this

Comment: check the password hached with the password in database ? check also the length , may be the column length in database is short and it's not saving the whole password

Comment: `$row` <> 1, it's actual a TRUE match there.. but without the third `=` that should be fine.  `var_dump(password_verify($upass, $userRow['PASSWORD']))` is false? Insert a new user, log the password at `insert` then run this and debug the returned pass. They also are the same?

Comment: Where do you set the value of `$upass` ?

Comment: $upass is sent from the login form

Comment: Why the second sql for `Count(*)`. Can you determine if that's actually the leg of logic that is failing here?

Comment: i just added the second sql to check it was only returning 1 row